# Object attribute issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I run the below code, I get

> AttributeError: monster instance has no attribute 'D'

What would I have to change so that Godzilla.D would return (in this case, with 2,3 as the params) 7?

```
def add(x):
    y = x + 1
    return y

class monster:
    def __init__(self, A, B):
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        C = A * B
        D = add(C)

Godzilla = monster(2,3)
Godzilla.D
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to set `D` as an attribute of the instance of `monster` being initialized in the `__init__` method. Change `D = add(C)` to `self.D = add(C)`.